# How can I rewrite the below parser code in Java

Tags: java, spring

I have written a simple parser in Java for a study project. Can anyone see how I might improve the code below. I have been looking at the code myself for the last few days but I couldn't come up with anything.

```
int counter = 0;
int cacheCounter = 0;



for(Map.Entry<String, File[]> path : queriedCache.entrySet()) {
        String[] array = new String[path.getValue().length];
        for(File file : queriedCache.get(path.getKey())) {
            if(file.listFiles() != null) {
                array = new String[Objects.requireNonNull(file.listFiles()).length + 1];
                for(File gif : Objects.requireNonNull(file.listFiles())) {
                    array[counter] = gif.getAbsolutePath();
                    counter++;
                }
                counter = 0;
            } else { 
                array[counter] = file.getAbsolutePath();
            }
            counter++;
        }
        counter = 0;
        cache[cacheCounter] = new CacheDto();
        cache[cacheCounter].setQuery(path.getKey());
        cache[cacheCounter].setGifs(array);
        cacheCounter++;
    }

    return cache;
```

Comment: Hi @Vadym - is there a reason why you have counter (other than for debugging?).  Perhaps some javadoc might help. And if one of the Files for that query is a directory you get all elements in that directory - what if some aren't GIFs, and what if there's a sub-sub-directory of GIFS??

Comment: Please explain what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Code Review requires code with sufficient context for reviewers to understand how that code is used. Please [**follow the tour**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/tour), and read [**"What topics can I ask about here?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/on-topic), [**"How do I ask a good question?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**"What types of questions should I avoid asking?"**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a _parser_.  What is the intent of the code?  Also, it looks incomplete - no classes, missing imports, undefined variables.  It's really not ready for review, but that you could easily fix that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First off, it would've been nice to see the entire method, or preferrably even the entire class. Having less context makes reviewing harder.

That said, I feel there was enough for a review, so here goes.

You call `file.listFiles` 3 times per file. It would probably be more efficient to store the result in a variable the first time you call it so you don't have to do it again.

On that note, both your `Objects.requireNonNull` calls are redundant - they're in a branch where you've already checked `file.listFiles()` isn't `null`.

Your code's behaviour seems *weird* when operating on a path containing both directories and files. At best the return value is weird and/or inconsistent. At worst, you might get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. To see how, let's look at a directory with the following content:

```
some_file.gif
some_folder/
    cat.gif
    dog.gif
thing.gif
thing2.gif
thing3.gif
thing4.gif
```

Now, we don't *know* what order `listFiles()` will return those files in. But let's assume they'll be returned in the order I listed them in above. What your code will do in that case is:

- Create an array `array` with length 6
- Iterate over the content of that folder:

  - Add `some_file.gif` to `array`
  - Notice that `some_folder` is a directory and iterate over that:

    - Replace `array` with a brand-new array with length 3. `some_file.gif` is lost in the process, which is not ideal
    - Add `some_folder/cat.gif` and `some_folder/dog.gif` to that array
    - Reset `counter` to 0
  - Add `thing.gif` to `array` at index 0, overwriting `some_folder/cat.gif` - not sure we want that
  - Add `thing2.gif` to `array` at index 1, overwriting `some_folder/dog.gif` too
  - Add `thing3.gif` to `array` at index 2. Fortunately, `array` has 3 spaces in it, so it fits
  - Add `thing4.gif` to `array` at index 3. `array` doesn't have an index 3, so we get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

I think what you want to do is use some sort of dynamically-sized `Collection<String>` to collect file paths. Much easier than keeping track of counters. Same for `cache`. If you really need arrays at the end, collections have a `toArray` method.

When you have a `Map.EntrySet`, you already know what values are associated with each key. Unless you're updating the map as you're working (which you aren't), `someMap.get(entry.getKey())` is just a more complicated way to say `entry.getValue()`

And, as Mr R pointed out in a comment, you only check for one level of directories. If you have a structure like:

```
one/
    two/
        three/
            hello.gif
```

...you'll return `one/two`, but I think you'd want to return `one/two/three/hello.gif`. If you want to check for arbitrary depths, you may want to look into a different approach for traversing the file system.

Putting it all together, I might do something a bit like

```java
public static CacheDto[] makeDTOs(Map<String, File[]> queriedCache) {
    Collection<CacheDto> cache = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, File[]> entry : queriedCache.entrySet()) {
        Collection<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        Queue<File> filesToCheck = new PriorityQueue<>(Arrays.asList(entry.getValue()));

        while ( ! filesToCheck.isEmpty() ) {
            File file = filesToCheck.poll();
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                for (File child : file.listFiles()) {
                    filesToCheck.add(child);
                }
            } else {
                files.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }

        CacheDto dto = new CacheDto();
        dto.setQuery(entry.getKey());
        dto.setGifs(paths.toArray(new String[0]));

        cache.add(dto);
    }

    return cache.toArray(new CacheDto[0]);
}
```

Comment: This question has one vote to close specifically for the reasons you cite at the beginning of the answer. I left the question open because you provided a good answer but in the future it might be better not to answer questions that seem to be off-topic.